# Iterar en listas fuera de rango

Tags: python

Tengo una lista de numeros en python:

```
tiempos = ["0.64", "0.83", "11.2", "12.1", "15.2", "15.9", "16.2", "16.8"]
```

Quiero iterar entre ellos para saber si

```
tiempos[1] - tiempos[0] > 2
```

... no solo con esos dos, sino con todos. Cuando lo intento con un contador i + 1 me sale fuera de rango.

Les pondre contexto: esos son los tiempos de diferencia entre una palabra y otra, es decir, la primera se dijo en el segundo 0.6, la segunda en el segundo 0.8 y la ultima en el segundo 16.8. Creare listas de palabras cuando estan juntas (para formar oraciones), y si se pasan de dos segudos es porque hay un punto y creare otra lista que represente otra oracion.

Ejemplo del codigo:

```
for index,x in enumerate(tiempos):
    proximo = index + 1 
    if float(x[proximo]) - float(x[index]) > 2:
        print("Es mayor")
```

**Si no se puede de esa forma lo que quiero es eso, saber si la que le sigue a la anterior es mayor a 2 o no.**

Comment: Es una iteracion for x in numeros: simple, por eso no la coloque.

Comment: Te recomiendo agregar ese código aunque sea simple, ya que así tu pregunta tendrá un ejemplo minimo y verificable que es lo que se pide que haya en las preguntas. Además de ser también una demostración de que lo haz intentado por ti mismo.

Comment: Si iteras como dices `for x in numeros`, entonces ¿cómo accedes al anterior? Además eso no se corresponde con lo que pones en la pregunta pues `numeros[0]` o `numeros[1]` está usando un índice para acceder a elementos de la lista, mientras que un `for x in numeros` no usaría índices.

Comment: Por otro lado, lo que tienes en la lista son cadenas. No las puedes restar.

Comment: Ya coloque el ejemplo.

Comment: El problema es que cuando estás en el último elemento, `proximo` será ya un índice de un elemento que no está en el array. Basta que en lugar de iterar por la lista completa iteres por la lista excepto el último elemento: `for index, x in enumerate(tiempos[:-1])`

Comment: También puedes hacer: `for x, siguiente in zip(tiempos, tiempos[1:]): if siguiente-proximo: ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que tenés varios errores. En principio, en el condicional estas intentando acceder a un elemento del *string* iterado. Es decir en el primer ciclo de bucle, `x = "0.64"`, luego en el condicional estas preguntando si el *float* de `"0.64"[1]` - el *float* de `"0.64"[0]` es mayor que 2. Ahí ya te tiraría el primer error y es que el float de `'.'` no existe. Fíjate si te sirve esta solución. La idea es pasar primero la lista de `stings` a una lista de `float` para operar directamente con floats. Saludos

```
tiempos = ["0.64", "0.83", "11.2", "12.1", "15.2", "15.9", "16.2", "16.8"]

tiempos = [float(i) for  i  in tiempos]

for i in range(len(tiempos)-1):
    if tiempos[i+1] - tiempos[i] > 2:
        print('Es mayor')
```

Comment: Mil gracias, Ariel por la tutoria y por la gran ayuda. Si funciono.

Answer (score 1):

Lo haría de la siguiente forma, asumiendo que cada posición de la lista tiempos es numérica y no string:

```
tiempos = [0.64, 0.83, 11.2, 12.1, 15.2, 15.9, 16.2, 16.8]

for i in range(1, len(tiempos)):
  Resta = tiempos[i] - tiempos[i -1]
  if Resta > 2:
    print('Es mayor a 2')
  else:
    print('No es mayor a 2')
```